# Замена css + localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, localstorage

Долго и упорно изобретал велосипед в виде color-switcher'a для сайта,
и я даже думал, что у меня получается, пока не перезагрузил страницу. После перезагрузки ожидаемо (но не для меня) `css` слетает к дефолтному. Гугл подсказал копать в сторону `localStorage`, но у меня так ничего и не вышло.

```
var colorSheets = [
        {
            color: "#f2fcfb",
            title: "Светлая тема",
            href: "default.css"
        },
        {
            color: "#000",
            title: "Тёмная тема",
            href: "dark.css"
        }
    ];

var ColorSwitcher = (function() {

function initColorSwitcher(colorSheets) {
    var tempCon, colorSwitcher, controlBtn, colorSwitchs, linkHolderHtml, linkHolder;

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(colorSheets) !== "[object Array]") {
        return;
    }

    tempCon = document.createDocumentFragment();

    colorSwitcher = document.createElement("div");
    colorSwitcher.classList.add("ColorSwitcher");

    controlBtn = document.createElement("button");
    controlBtn.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__control");

    colorSwitchs = document.createElement("div");
    colorSwitchs.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__switchs");

    linkHolderHtml = document.createElement("link");
    linkHolderHtml.rel = "stylesheet";
    linkHolderHtml.id = "ColorSwitcherLinkHolder";
    document.head.appendChild(linkHolderHtml);

    linkHolder = document.getElementById("ColorSwitcherLinkHolder");

    colorSheets.forEach(function(colorSheet, index) {
        var colorSwitch;

        if (colorSheet.color && colorSheet.title && colorSheet.href) {
            colorSwitch = document.createElement("button");

            colorSwitch.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__switch")
            colorSwitch.title = colorSheet.title;
            colorSwitch.dataset.index = index;
            colorSwitch.style.backgroundColor = colorSheet.color;

            colorSwitchs.appendChild(colorSwitch);
        }
    });

    colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var index;

        if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
            return;
        }

        index = event.target.dataset.index;
        linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
        return false;
    });

    controlBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("ColorSwitcher--open");

        return false;
    });

    colorSwitcher.appendChild(controlBtn);
    colorSwitcher.appendChild(colorSwitchs);
    tempCon.appendChild(colorSwitcher);
    document.body.appendChild(tempCon);
}

return {
    init: initColorSwitcher
};
})();
```

Пытался сохранять это:

```
    colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var index;

    if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
        return;
    }

    index = event.target.dataset.index;
    localStorage.setItem("key", index);
    linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
    return false;
});
```

и это

```
    colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var index;

    if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
        return;
    }

    index = event.target.dataset.index;
    linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
    localStorage.setItem("key", linkHolder);
    return false;
});
```

внутри функции и за её пределами, но `localStorage` как был пуст, так и остался.
Я уже сдался. Можно решить проблему парой строчек правильного кода или мне нужно начинать всё с начала?

П.с. я совсём зелёный

```js
"use strict";
var colorSheets = [
            {
                color: "#b0eae6",
                title: "Light",
                href: "default.css"
            },
            {
                color: "#f3e686",
                title: "Gold",
                href: "gold.css"
            },
            {
                color: "#000",
                title: "Dark",
                href: "dark.css"
            }   
        ];

var ColorSwitcher = (function() {
    
    function initColorSwitcher(colorSheets) {
        var tempCon, colorSwitcher, controlBtn, colorSwitchs, linkHolderHtml, linkHolder;

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(colorSheets) !== "[object Array]") {
            return;
        }

        tempCon = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
        colorSwitcher = document.createElement("div");
        colorSwitcher.classList.add("ColorSwitcher");

        controlBtn = document.createElement("button");
        controlBtn.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__control");

        colorSwitchs = document.createElement("div");
        colorSwitchs.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__switchs");

        linkHolderHtml = document.createElement("link");
        linkHolderHtml.rel = "stylesheet";
        linkHolderHtml.id = "ColorSwitcherLinkHolder";
        document.head.appendChild(linkHolderHtml);

        linkHolder = document.getElementById("ColorSwitcherLinkHolder");

        colorSheets.forEach(function(colorSheet, index) {
            var colorSwitch;

            if (colorSheet.color && colorSheet.title && colorSheet.href) {
                colorSwitch = document.createElement("button");

                colorSwitch.classList.add("ColorSwitcher__switch")
                colorSwitch.title = colorSheet.title;
                colorSwitch.dataset.index = index;
                colorSwitch.style.backgroundColor = colorSheet.color;
                
                colorSwitchs.appendChild(colorSwitch);
            }
        });

        colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            var index;

            if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
                return;
            }

            index = event.target.dataset.index;
            linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
            return false;
        });

        controlBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("ColorSwitcher--open");

            return false;
        });

        colorSwitcher.appendChild(controlBtn);
        colorSwitcher.appendChild(colorSwitchs);
        tempCon.appendChild(colorSwitcher);
        document.body.appendChild(tempCon);
    }

    return {
        init: initColorSwitcher
    };
})();
```

```css
.ColorSwitcher,
.ColorSwitcher * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ColorSwitcher {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: -162px;
    width: 162px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-80%);
            transform: translateY(-80%);
    -webkit-transition: left .2s;
    transition: left .2s;
}

.ColorSwitcher--open {
    left: 0;
}

.ColorSwitcher__control,
.ColorSwitcher__switch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.ColorSwitcher__control:focus,
.ColorSwitcher__switch:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.ColorSwitcher__control {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff463a;
}

.ColorSwitcher__control:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 70%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.ColorSwitcher--open .ColorSwitcher__control {
    background: #fff;
}



.ColorSwitcher__switchs {
    margin: -5px;
}

.ColorSwitcher__switch {
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes controlSpin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
                transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes controlSpin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
                transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
<script>
ColorSwitcher.init(colorSheets);
</script>
```

Comment: Не вижу использования localStorage в приложенном коде

Comment: Не вижу вызова `initColorSwitcher` в приложенном коде.

Comment: Пардон, добавил жалкие попытки использования localStorage. Сохранённые ключи искал в devTools, там пусто.
`initColorSwitcher` вызывается в `html`

Comment: а где `localStorage.getItem`?

Comment: Так чтобы получить ключ, нужно чтобы он сохранился. А по скольку localStorage у меня пустой, то ничего не сохраняется. 
В консоли devtools пробовал (для теста, проверить синтаксис на правильность, и вообще) `localStorage.setItems("key","value")` В локальном хранилище появляются соответствующие ключи.

Comment: Хотел добавить сниппет, не получается. 
`сolorSwitcher is not defined`

Но если код подключаю как внешний файл, сниппет работает.

Comment: Приведите минимальный работающий код. Без готово проектика очень сложно сказать что-то определенное.

Comment: Добавил сниппет, но как писал выше, он выполняется с ошибкой.
Хотя если тот же скрипт как внешний файл прикрепить, то будет работать.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понял, почему ключ в `localStorage` не сохранялся. Разделили на две функции - заработало.

Заменил

```
colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
var index;
if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
return;
}
index = event.target.dataset.index;
localStorage.setItem("key", index);
linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
return false;
});
```

на

```
function swapCss(e) {
var index;
if (e.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") {
return;
}
index = e.target.dataset.index;
linkHolder.href = colorSheets[index].href;
};
function saveIndex(e) {
var index;
index = e.target.dataset.index;
localStorage["index"] = index;
};
colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", saveIndex, false);   
colorSwitchs.addEventListener("click", swapCss, false);
```